# Django: set the 'through' argument for ManyToMany field in the extended class

Tags: django, manytomanyfield

I want to extend an abstract model class with a ManyToMany field and set the field's `through` argument to refer to my own model/table. I tried the following, inspired by this: [How to override the default value of a Model Field from an Abstract Base Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6377631/how-to-override-the-default-value-of-a-model-field-from-an-abstract-base-class/6379556#6379556)

```
# first_app    
class A(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)


class B(models.Model):
    a = models.ManyToManyField(A)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

# myapp: my extended and through models
class C(B):
    pass
C._meta.get_field('a').through = 'D'

class D(models.Model):
    a = models.ForeignKey(A)
    c = models.ForeignKey(C)
    default_rel = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

The problem is Django creates both `myapp_c_a` and `myapp_d` tables, and uses `myapp_c_a` instead of `myapp_d`, which means it ignores the `through` argument.

So, my question is how I can override the ManyToMany field in C so it uses D.