# Django: add index to meta field

Tags: django, django-models

I have the following model:

```
from model_utils.models import TimeStampedModel
class MyModel(TimeStampedModel):
    ....
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    ....
```

This model is based on Django Utils (https://django-model-utils.readthedocs.org/en/latest/models.html#timestampedmodel) which adds `created` and `modified` fields to my model.

What I need know is way to add a `db_index` to the modified field of my model. But I can't modify the TimeStampedModel file because it is part of an external dependency.

Do you know any easy solution for this kind of issue?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you can using model Meta.

if you don't need to inherit meta from the TimeStampedModel just use this:

```
class Meta:
   ...
```

otherwise you need to explicitly tell django to look into the parent's meta first like this:

```
class Meta(TimeStampedModel.Meta):
```

this might be a hackish solution but maybe you can try using index_together to make django create an index for your model:

like this:

```
class Meta(TimeStampedModel.Meta):
    index_together = [
        ["modified",],
    ]
```

try it out and tell me if it worked

EDIT:

Another solution coming from: [How to override the default value of a Model Field from an Abstract Base Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6377631/how-to-override-the-default-value-of-a-model-field-from-an-abstract-base-class/6379556#6379556):

try adding this to your MyModel class

```
MyModel._meta.get_field('modified').db_index = True
```

Comment: I used the last solution and it worked perfectly. Fells less hacky than index_together.